# How do not use findViewById?

Tags: android, kotlin

Usually we do not use findViewById (R.id.listView) in kotlin because Android studio do it for us automatically (we do not need to find view).
But [this](https://kotlintutorialspoint.wordpress.com/2018/03/30/context-menu-using-kotlin-in-android/) example shows that we need to you it (in this line of code):

```
val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView) as ListView.
```

Why do we use this line in this example? How to not use it?

Comment: If you are using kotlin synthetic library then you don't need to use findViewById otherwise you need to call findViewById to get the reference of any view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) from Kotlin, you should never need a cast (from API level 26 and up). You should use it one of these two ways:

```
val myTV1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
val myTV2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
```

And then you can access its properties via these variables:

```
myTV1.text = "testing"
```

This is a perfectly valid way of getting View references and using them in Kotlin as it is.

---

However, if you also have [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) enabled in the project (by the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` line in your module level `build.gradle` file), you also can refer to your Views by their IDs via the synthetic properties it provides, just make sure you have the correct imports, for example:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myTextView.text = "testing"
    }

}
```

Note that Kotlin Android Extensions is entirely optional to use, and if you do use it, `findViewById` of course is still available if for whatever reason you want to mix the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you need a view from a layout file, you can import the following:

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout filename>.<id of view>
```

If you need all of the views from a layout file, you can use:

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout filename>.*
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only applicable for Kotlin

**Step 1:**
Add this Kotlin Android Extensions in our code

Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

NOTE: Now you can directly access the view id without using findViewbyId, in case if you face any red line press alt+enter, or import this in KT file.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_your_layout.*
```